# How can I read notifications bar on Windows 7 in script?

Tags: windows, shell, notifications

Looking for bash/shell script where I can read notifications

Picture:
[image]

Just need to read text from notifications (probably list or array) and then make specific handling (If concrete text appears).

Problem is to find out how and where are that informations in Windows system.

I just found some API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/notification-area

But I am bit lost at it... (new at shell scripting)

Solution should be without installing additional libraries.

Comment: Windows *UI Automation* (or MSAA) APIs will allow you to enumerate them & fetch the current text.